# Matrix with all eigenvalues equal to $0$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix with all eigenvalues equal to zero. How does it follows that $A$ is nilpotent? In my text this is used without further argument but I don't see this straight away.

Comment: What is the characteristic polynomial of such a matrix?

Comment: Do you know Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah your second explanation makes sense. I'm not sure about Cayley-Hamilton theorem. I remember it while I looked it up. Characteristic polynomial is $det(A-X \cdot I)$ right? How does that prove the statement?

Comment: If you combine Nûr's comment with mine, you'll find that $\chi_A(A)=(-1)^nA^n=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by *"all eigenvalues equal to zero"* for a real matrix? Are all eigenvalues of $A:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ equal to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a matrix $A\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has the eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n$ then it is nilpotent. After all, this means that $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $n$, so it is an $n$-fold root of the characteristic polynomial $P_A(X)$ of $A$. This is a polynomial of of degree $n$ so $P_A(X)=X^n$. Cayley-Hamilton tells us that $A^n=P_A(A)=0$, so indeed $A$ is nilpotent.

Note that the phrase *"all eigenvalues equal to zero"* is a bit ambiguous. The real matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$
has all *real* eigenvalues equal to zero, but it is not nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm yeah you are right, that is ambiguous indeed. I'm surprised then that they draw this conclusion in the syllabus. It is stated that for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $A > 0$ en $\rho(A) = 0$, then $A$ is nilpotent. Is this then technically speaking incorrect? I'm surprised by the lack of explanation of this statement.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by $A>0$ and $\rho(A)=0$.

Comment: $A>0$ means every entry of $A$ is positive, and $\rho(A) = \{|\lambda|: \lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A\}$.

Comment: Then it seems that $A>0$ should imply that all eigenvalues of $A$ are real? I don't see any geometric intepretation of $A>0$ though...

Answer (score 1):

A very explicit way to do so would use the Jordan normal form $J$ of your matrix, which looks like

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & ...
\\ 0 & 0  & 1  & 0 & ...
\\ \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots
\\ 0 & ... & & 0 \end{array} \right).$$

There may be several 1's on the off-diagonal, or also zeroes. If you multiply this matrix with itself, the row of 1's moves one step to the upper right. So you can convince yourself that the $n$-th power of this matrix is the zero matrix. Since we have $A^n = T J^n T^*$ with the transformation matrices $T$, it follows also that $A^n = 0$.