# Prove $\lVert A \rVert _{p} \geq 1$ for any idempotent matrix $A \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms, idempotents

As the title states,

I'm facing a problem to prove:

- for any idempotent matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $A \neq 0$, $\lVert A \rVert_{p} \geq 1$.

Here the p-norm $\lVert A \rVert_{p}$ satisfies the properties:

1. $\lVert A + B \rVert_{p} \leq \lVert A \rVert_{p} + \lVert B \rVert_{p}$
2. $\lVert A B \rVert_{p} \leq \lVert A \rVert_{p}  \lVert B \rVert_{p}$
3. $\lVert \alpha A \rVert_{p} = |\alpha|\lVert A \rVert_{p}$
4. $\lVert A \rVert_{p} = 0$  iff $A = 0$.

and is defined as: $\lVert A \rVert_{p} = \max_{\lVert x \rVert_{p} = 1} \lVert Ax \rVert_{p}$

I'm quite confused about how to build a connection between any p-norm of a complex matrix and a real number.

I have a feeling that maybe this connection need to be built by eigenvalue? But haven't figured out yet.

I have proved that

- $I-A$ is idempotent if $A$ is idempotent.
- $0$ and $1$ are the only possible eigenvalues of an idempotent matrix.

Any hints or solutions you could offer? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please define the "p norm" of a matrix and state its key properties.  Is it submultiplicative?

Comment: @user8675309 I have uploaded the properties and definition~ and yes it is submultiplicative.

Comment: The first property should read $\|A+B\|_p \le \|A\|_p + \|B\|_p$, it seems.

Comment: **hint:** use idempotence and submultiplicativity to get the answer.  The answer should be a 1-liner.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Thanks a lot! I have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any square matrix, the eigenvalues are bounded by the operator (p-) norm, i.e.
$$ \|A\|_p \geq \lambda$$
for any eigenvector $\lambda$. This is a basic fact:
Let $x$ be an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, i.e. $Ax = \lambda x$. Then,
$$\|Ax\|_p \leq \|A\|_p\|x\|_p$$
but also
$$\|Ax\|_p = \|\lambda x\|_p = |\lambda|\|x\|_p.$$

So, if you have shown that an idempotent matrix $A$ only has eigenvalues $1$ and $0$, you already know $\|A\|_p \geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But why it doesn't get $\lVert A \rVert _{p} \geq 0$, since 0  is the smallest eigenvalue ?

Comment: Well, the operator norm does not only bound the smallest eigenvalue, it bounds all eigenvalues. Since you require your matrix to be non-zero (and an idempotent), you know it has the eigenvalue 1 with at least multiplicativity 1. So, you get your result.

Comment: Sorry I'm so unfamiliar with this topic, why the matrix has eigenvalue 1 with at least multiplicativity 1?

Comment: If you had only $0$ as an eigenvalue, your matrix would have to be either the zero matrix or nilpotent (i.e. $A^n = 0$ for any $n > 1$). Since $A$ is idempotent, this is not possible. So, since you have only $0$ and $1$ as possible eigenvalues, your largest eigenvalue is $1$.

Comment: Really thanks, I finally understand. I also find the same question for "matrix has only $0$ eigenvalue" for others who may concerned: {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2784988}

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer if it is now clear to you?